# Why typeclasses instead of just pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typeclass

This is something of a philosophical question, but one I hope to have answered by official documentation or “word of god” (read: SPJ). Is there a specific reason that the Haskell committee chose to require explicit interfaces in the form of typeclasses rather than a more uniform solution based on pattern-matching?

As an example, take `Eq`:

```
class Eq a where
    (==), (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x == y = not $ x /= y
    x /= y = not $ x == y

instance Eq Int where
    (==) = internalIntEq
```

Why could we not do something like this instead (bear with the pseudo-Haskell):

```
(==), (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
default x == y = not $ x /= y             -- 1
default x /= y = not $ x == y

(Int a) == (Int b) = a `internalIntEq` b  -- 2
```

That is, if Haskell were to allow pattern-matching of ordinary data types, then:

- Programmers could create ad-hoc classes, i.e., `instance` would be implicit (2)
- Types could still be inferred and matched statically (`SupportsEqualsEquals a => ...`)
- Default implementations would come “for free”
- Classes could readily be extended without breaking anything

There would need to be a way to specify a default pattern (1) that, though declared before others, always matches last. Do any of these hypothetical features clash with something inherent in Haskell? Would it become difficult or impossible to correctly infer types? It seems like a powerful feature that’d gel very well with the rest of Haskell, so I figure there’s a good reason We Don’t Do It That Way™. Is this mechanism of ad-hoc polymorphism simply *too* ad-hoc?

Comment: I'm not well-versed in this, but I think one major problem is that you lose parametricity, and thus free theorems: you know what `id :: a -> a` or `fst :: (a,b) -> a` do simply by their type signatures, because they only have parametric polymorphism.  If you have some sort of typecase mechanism, then you lose parametricity.  For instance, `a -> a -> Bool` admits only two (total) implementations in Haskell (`const $ const True` and `const $ const False`); if you have typecase, then you lose this guarantee.

Comment: @AntalS-Z: Just making sure I understand you correctly. Are you saying I could declare `id :: a -> a`, then define `id (Int i) = i + 1`? Because that’s not the case: the latter definition would be of type `SupportsPlus a => a -> a`, which is incompatible.

Comment: That's what it sounds like from your question; your type signature for `(==)` is given as `a -> a -> Bool`.  If you have to specify a "type class" `SupportsEquals`, then it seems all you've done is traded syntax around---I don't see why it's *different*.  And I don't think it can express multi-parameter type classes, functional dependencies, or associated types, although these certainly weren't in the original plan.  In fact, can it even express higher-kinded type classes?  How would you know that `return :: a -> m a` should be ad-hoc over `m`, and not `a`?

Comment: @JonPurdy How did it acquire that type? `i` is manifestly an `Int`, how did that get backed out to `SupportsPlus a => a`? Does the same generalization rule, whatever it is, apply to all definitions or only to ones using the typecase notation? Does this mean, even absent a global `id :: a -> a` signature, that `id (Int i) = i + 1` has type `SupportsPlus a => a -> a"? If so, what are the semantics of expressions like `id 3.7`?

Comment: @AntalS-Z: The difference is inversion of who “owns” the interface information. Right now, a typeclass defines which operations are allowed for the type parameter. This way, the type itself defines which operations are allowed. I’m not sure why multi-parameter typeclasses would need to be any different, other than that you still need fundeps, but those could go in the function/operator declaration. But I think you’re right—`Monad` may be where it fails. Could you help me out with a specific example?

Comment: @DougMcClean: Just to be clear, you couldn’t possibly deduce ad-hoc classes without explicit type signatures, and I’m not suggesting that. The `SupportsPlus` (or whatever it’d be called) comes from the use of `+` in the (incorrect) definition of `id`. I see where I was wrong, though—there is something of an ambiguity between `Int -> Int` and `SupportsPlus a => a -> a`, because neither is fully correct.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I'm not sure what you mean by "the type itself defines which operations are allowed."  From your example, it seems that the *function* would define which types are allowed.  And if the signature is required, is your type for `(==)` in error?  As for cases that seem problematic: higher-kinded type variables and types in non-argument positions.  Consider `maxBound :: Enum a => a` or `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`---how would matching work here?  (By the way, I like the question, even if I'm not quite clear on the details.)

Comment: @AntalS-Z: Shall we move this discussion to chat?

Comment: @JonPurdy: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7265/why-typeclasses-instead-of-just-pattern-matching-chat

Comment: I'm strongly opposed to the close vote. It's an open-ended, subjective question, sure. But I think it's a wonderful intellectual exercise to explore why a language was designed in a certain way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this mechanism of ad-hoc polymorphism simply too ad-hoc?

This question simply begs to be linked to Philip Wadler and Steve Blott's 1988 paper, [How to make ad-hoc polymorphism less ad-hoc](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/class/class.ps), where they present the idea of Type classes. Wadler is probably "word of God" on this one.

There are a few problems I see with the proposed "pattern match on any Haskell data type" technique.

The pattern matching technique is **not sufficient to define polymorphic constants**, such as `mempty :: Monoid a => a`.

The pattern matching technique still falls back onto type classes, except in a worse way. Type classes *classify types* (go figure). But the pattern matching technique makes it rather vague. How exactly are you supposed to specify that functions `foo` and `bar` are part of the "same" class? **Typeclass constraints would become utterly unreadable** if you have to add a new one for every single polymorphic function you use.

The pattern matching technique introduces new syntax into Haskell, **complicating the language specification**. The `default` keyword doesn't look so bad, but pattern matching "on types" is new and confusing.

Pattern matching "on ordinary data types" defeats pointfree style. Instead of `(==) = intEq`, we have `(Int a) == (Int b) = intEq a b`; this sort of artificial pattern match **prevents eta-reduction**.

Finally, it **completely changes our understanding of type signatures.** `a -> a -> Foo` is currently a *guarantee* that the inputs cannot be inspected. Nothing can be assumed about the `a` inputs, except that the two inputs are of the same type. `[a] -> [a]` again means the elements of the list *cannot be inspected* in any meaningful way, giving you [Theorems for Free](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/free/free.ps) (another Wadler paper).

There may be ways to address these concerns, but my overall impression is that Type classes already solve this problem in an elegant way, and the suggested pattern matching technique adds no benefit, while causing several problems.

Comment: wrt. your last point, I don't think his suggestion is to change polymorphism entirely, I think it's just to add a bunch of type constraints for each function used. i.e. `a -> a -> Foo` would still guarantee the inputs cannot be inspected -- if an implicit typeclass is used, that becomes part of the signature.

Comment: Thanks very much for the insight, and the paper. I disagree with a couple of your points, though. Typeclass constraints wouldn’t become unreadable, because they wouldn’t even need to be visible—you could just say “`(+) not defined in (foo::Foo + bar::Bar)`”. The point about type signatures is important. You know for a fact that `id :: a -> a` still, because a definition involving any other function would have an incompatible signature. Also, re. eta-reduction, you’re writing in an applicative (as opposed to concatenative) language, so not everything can be point-free anyway.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: Yes, that’s exactly what I mean. It doesn’t break any of the theorems we already have. At least I don’t think so.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the Word of God, but here are a few arguments.

*No longer is defining a function in the same module unique*. You can now write

```
(==) = internalIntEq
(==) = internalFloatEq
```

This makes code less readable. There's a proposal called "TypeBasedNameResolution" which does something similar, but the important fact is that such type branching is only done for `(==)`'s from different modules.

*It's bad practice to have the compiler adding in identifiers*. In your case, you automatically create type class `SupportsEqualsEquals`. A new user might ask, "where does this come from", and there'd be no corresponding source defining it.

*Skipping writing instance signatures doesn't give you as much as you might think*. You can get the necessary parameters via e.g. `:t internalIntEq` in ghci. I guess it could be more convenient, but I'd rather have a tool I could ask "what's the instance type for `Eq` where `==` is `internalIntEq`.".

*More advanced class features are unclear*. Where do you put associated types and functional dependencies? These are really important to me!!

*Your defaulting makes modular compilation more difficult*. You're not going to get extensible classes for free. Consider,

```
f :: Supports[==] a => a -> a -> Bool
f = (/=)
```

As I understand it, this compiles down into

```
f :: Instance (Supports[==]) a -> a -> a -> Bool
f eq_inst x y = not (x eq_inst.== y)
```

Now, if I provide a new `/=` instance for a particular type `a_0`, and feed some `x :: a_0` into `f`, then

```
f x x = not (x == x)
-- computation you really want: f x x = x /= x, using the new /= instance for a_0
```

You might ask, "when would one be so dumb to restrict `f` to `Supports[==]` instead of `Supports[/=]`?" But, contexts can come from a more than function signatures; they can come from higher-order functions, etc., etc.

Hope it helps.