# Check type of parameter in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function `(a->a)` which can take in different types but is there a way to determine what datatype the parameter is?
Like

```
foo :: a -> a
foo a == int =..
foo a == char =..
```

Is there anyway to do a check like this in haskell?

Comment: No, that would break parametricity.

Comment: But the parameter is known at compile time. It makes no sense to do that. You probably want to use a typeclass here.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9106980/1848654. The construct you're describing is also known as "typecase".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Use a datatype instead:

```
data MyType = MyInt Int | MyChar Char

foo :: MyType -> MyType
foo (MyInt i) = MyInt (i + 1) -- Or whatever
foo (MyChar c) = case c of {'a' -> MyChar 'A'; k -> MyChar k}
```

Though this of course restricts what types you can use.

Alternatively, use a typeclass:

```
class MyClass a where
    foo :: a -> a

instance MyClass Int where
    foo i = i + 1

instance MyClass Char where
    foo c = case c of {'a' -> 'A'; k -> k}

-- N.B. foo :: MyClass a => a -> a
```

Though once again this restricts what types you can use.

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this, which however I do *not* recommend, is to add a `Typeable` constraint.

```
foo :: forall a . Typeable a => a -> a
foo x = case eqT :: a :~: Int of -- check if a = Int
   Just Refl -> x + 1            -- here we can use x as an Int
   Nothing   -> x                -- here we can not use x as an Int
```

For this to work you need a number of extensions, such as `ScopedTypeVariables` and `GADTs`.

This is usually not a good idea, in general. Before adopting this, you should first understand if you really need it: `Typeable` is very powerful and it should be used as a last resort, when simpler alternatives are not enough. Perhaps a custom type class could be a better solution for your tasks, as AJFarmar showed.

Also note that, without a type class constraint, a function `foo :: a -> a`, according to its "free theorem" (AKA parametricity property) can only be the identity function, or be undefined (e.g. infinite recursion, or a runtime exception).

Comment: Note that this is a "safe" way around parametricity because this is essentially the same as `foo :: TypeRep a -> a -> a`, which is still parametrically polymorphic.